# Why dir_module does NOT seem to load, although clearly it is loaded in httpd.conf and modules folder?

Tags: php, apache, module, dir, system-administration

I checked the httpd.conf file which has "LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
" uncommented already. I also check the apache modules folder seeing that mod_dir.so is there too. BUT still the module_dir does not seem to have loaded at all.

Because when I tried to set up this virtual folder, if I put the line 
     Alias /myblog "D:/php/try"
inside the ifmodule directive like the following:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
    Alias /myblog "D:/php/try"
   <Directory "d:/php/try">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   </Directory> 
</IfModule>
```

It would NOT work, when accessed by url /blog apache says error 404 not found.

But if I put the line
       Alias /myblog "D:/php/try"
outside the ifmodule directive, then the line will work and apache can find the folder. So I think it's  because the module_dir hasn't been loaded yet.

But how can I load it? I already checked the two places as mentioned above which seem to suggest that it is loaded already. Please help. Thanks in advance.

p.s. My platform is windows 7

Comment: Can you please show your config, at least for the virtual host? Any .htaccess? Maybe there is AllowOverride -Indexes? If you suspect that module_dir is not being loaded, then you can remove the ifmodule check around the DirectoryIndex setting and confirm by getting an error from configtest.

Comment: And the config file also has this line:LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so

Comment: Just to double-check, are you restarting apache after you change the config? Can you try: <Location /server-info>
  SetHandler server-info
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from all
 </Location>   and post the output of /server-info to pastebin or similar?

Comment: <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
        Alias /myblog "D:/php/try"
       <Directory "d:/php/try">
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       </Directory> 
    </IfModule>

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nj2qbcre

Comment: I have added the location directive and pasted the localhost/server-info to that link: http://pastebin.com/nj2qbcre

Comment: It works now. Weird. And when I remove the Alias line it still works.

Comment: I think it's probably my browser's cache!

Comment: It's solved now. It's my browser's cache....Thank you for helping me to check it up and locate where the problem is...... I see you are from quebec...So, Merci beaucoup...（I'm learning French part time）

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<IfModule>` tags and only have `DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml` (in httpd.conf). That works for me in Windows 7 environment.