# http://localhost:8080 says access denied

Tags: php, apache

I installed Apache 2.4 using the msi installer and when I type localhost on the browser I get the message 'It works'.

I configured the httpd.conf file by adding the following lines

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

I also add index.php to `DirectoryIndex`variable in the `httpd.conf` file, uncommented `extension_dir = “ext”` in `php.ini` file

Created `index.php` in `htdocs` folder and when I try http://localhost:8080 in the browser it says access denied.

Can anyone help? I followed the instructions as per http://vitalflux.com/php-install-apache-2-4-php-5-6-windows/

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Apache that `index.php` is a valid directory index. If it doesn't find a valid directory index file and directory listing is disabled, it will throw a `403 Access Denied`.

Apend this to your `httpd.conf`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Remember to restart the Apache server so the changes will take effect.

Comment: My httpd.conf file has already the following code,
`<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex  index.php index.html
</IfModule>`

Are you suggesting to remove the `index.heml` and keep only `index..php`?

Comment: Strangely now, I can't find Apache in the Windows services. When I start the service from start menu option, the command prompt show up with the following message `The system cannot find the file specified: AH00436: No installed server named Apache2.4`

Should I rename the apache folder in my C drive to apache2.4?

Comment: @Justin This line indicates `DirectoryIndex index.php` will only be considered if `dir_module` is enabled. This might not be the case. You can see there's a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516573/why-dir-module-does-not-seem-to-load-although-clearly-it-is-loaded-in-httpd-con

Comment: `LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so` is already enabled in the `httpd.conf` file

Like I had mentioned, there is no apache server at all in windows services. I cannot start the apache server at the moment.

Comment: @Justin As you could see in the other post, this might not work correctly on Windows and can be misleading.